# Android drawing button to canvas with custom view?

Tags: android, button, canvas, custom-view

How can I draw a button on top of the canvas in a custom view? (Preferably on the mid-right side) Is there something I have to call before doing the button.draw(canvas)?

```
    public class MyClass extends View {
    public Simulation(Context context) {
            super(context);
            pauseButton.setText("TestButton");
            pauseButton.setClickable(true);
            pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Button Pressed!");
            }
            });
    public onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);
           pauseButton.draw(canvas);
    }
    }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: 'super.onDraw(canvas);' did not fix the problem? @Nammari

Comment: What is the current situation. Is it drawing atall? or drawing at wrong place?

Comment: It's currently not drawing at all. My guess is that its drawing it underneath the canvas/custom view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot insert a button into canvas. Canvas is an interface for bitmap or a bitmap buffer for a view. You can only draw other bitmap or pixels in it, not insert an object or a widget.

There are some solutions:

1. as Nikolay suggested, use a **FrameLayout** and create two layers (views), first your custom view and the second LinerView or RelativeView, which will come on top, where you can have buttons etc
2. draw an image of a buttun on Canvas then use **onTouchEvent** in your custom view and test for the coordinates of the touch, then do something... an example for onTouchEvent here: [Make certain area of bitmap transparent on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch/5439357#5439357)

Comment: How would I add my custom view to the xml file? Thanks for your answer

Comment: That is a long story, you have to search for examples...but basically you create a new tag like <my.packet.MyView>.... </my.packet.MyView> in xml and then create a new class called MyView extends View which has a constructor MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){ super(context, attrs); ....}  in this example just add the constructor i mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308106/view-inflation-and-custom-views

Answer (score 6):

Why do you need to draw the button yourself? Use a FrameLayout and simply have the button overlayed on your custom view.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       canvas.save();
       pauseButton.draw(canvas);
       canvas.restore();
}
```