# Android: Adding canvas into layout without covering other elements

Tags: android, canvas

I add a Button and TextView in my program,

which I set them on the same row.

Then I try to add a canvas on the second row,

However it somehow cover my button and TextView on the first row.

Here's my code from MainActivity.java, onCreate() method:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("DotSmasher");
    canvas = new DotSmasherCanvas(getBaseContext());
    //some other codes here


    //Toggle button
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton.setText("Stop");
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.addView(canvas);
    layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    textSec = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSec);
    //Rest of codes here
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

[image: This is my activity_main.xml]

I want to add canvas below those two items (Button and TextView).

How should I do that?

Comment: A canvas is not a type of view in Android.  Are you saying you want to create a custom view that you can draw into?

Comment: Yes.  I am still new to programming, what I am trying to do is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048103/android-drawing-button-to-canvas-with-custom-view   The first solution from this link.  I want those 2 elements to be outside of canvas